# What is logical query proccessing taken by HAVING clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, having

I'm pretty new in sql language, so I'm reading Sql Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals book to introduce myself in these topics. There are 2 examples that I'm trying to dissect to get a clear understanding about. First, the author execute the following query:

```
SELECT
    empid,
    YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear,
    SUM(freight) AS totalfreight,
    COUNT(*) AS numorders 
FROM 
    Sales.Orders 
WHERE 
    custid = 71
GROUP BY 
    empid, YEAR(orderdate);
```

to obtain this:

```
empid       orderyear   totalfreight          numorders
----------- ----------- --------------------- -----------
1           2006        126.56                1
2           2006        89.16                 1
9           2006        214.27                1
1           2007        711.13                2
2           2007        352.69                1
3           2007        297.65                2
4           2007        86.53                 1
5           2007        277.14                3
6           2007        628.31                3
7           2007        388.98                1
8           2007        371.07                4
1           2008        357.44                3
2           2008        672.16                2
4           2008        651.83                3
6           2008        227.22                1
7           2008        1231.56               2
```

But, in the 2nd example the author runs the following query:

```
SELECT 
    empid, YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear
FROM 
    Sales.Orders
WHERE 
    custid = 71
GROUP BY 
    empid, YEAR(orderdate)
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This query returns the following output:

```
empid       orderyear
----------- -----------
1           2007
3           2007
5           2007
6           2007
8           2007
1           2008
2           2008
4           2008
7           2008
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the resultset excluding 2006 years? and
2. why there are two rows with 1 values?
3. How `HAVING` clause does determine what rows return in both columns?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what your confusing is.  Perhaps if you included `count(*)` in the output of the second query it would be obvious:  only rows where `count(*)` is greater than 1 are included.

Comment: All of 2006 has only a single row per group. Emp 1 appears twice for two different years. `HAVING` operates on groups which were defined (in the `GROUP BY` as the combination of employee and year.

Answer (score 1):

In the first query, we see this:

```
COUNT(*) AS numorders
```

And in the second:

```
COUNT(*) > 1;
```

In the second query, this value isn't displayed, but we can use the first set of results to figure it out.  All of these rows are *not included* in the second query:

```
empid       orderyear   totalfreight          numorders
----------- ----------- --------------------- -----------
1           2006        126.56                1
2           2006        89.16                 1
9           2006        214.27                1
2           2007        352.69                1
4           2007        86.53                 1
7           2007        388.98                1
6           2008        227.22                1
```

Why?

Because `numorders` is only 1 and in the second query, we asked for rows where `numorders > 1`.

As to your question, `HAVING` is the version of `WHERE` that works on functions (such as `COUNT()`).

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: hello @Draco18s, thank you for your answer. I thought that having clause only was taking empid and orderyear columns for filtering the set. But, according to your response, HAVING is taking into account numorders, although it's not part of the secod query.

Comment: @DaniAya `numorders` is just an alias for the `COUNT(*)` call in the first query, but that same value has a logical effect in the second.

Answer (score 0):

You use `HAVING` together with `GROUP BY`.

The criteria used in `WHERE` applies to all rows before aggregation, while `HAVING` applies to the aggregated results.

In other words: You have two criteria sections for filtering the dataset; before the grouping defined in `WHERE`, and after grouping defined in `HAVING`.